# AVR - GNU linker script - How to get the load address of .data section

Tags: assembly, avr, bare-metal, linker-scripts

I'm quite new with GNU linker scripts. Want to create a bare-metal (without `avr-libc`) application for an AVR MCU. In an early phase from the project I didn't need to initialize the `.data` section. But now I need it.

My current linker script:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-avr)
OUTPUT_ARCH(avr51)

ENTRY(_start)

MEMORY {
    FLASH_APP   (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 120K
    FLASH_BOOT  (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x0001E000, LENGTH = 8K
    SRAM        (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x00800100, LENGTH = 16K
}

STACK_SIZE = 4K;

SECTIONS {
    .text : {
        _text_s = .;
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
        *(.text)
        *(.text*)
        _text_e = .;
    } > FLASH_BOOT
    
    .rodata : {
        . = ALIGN(2);
        _rodata_s = .;
        *(.rodata)
        *(.rodata*)
        _rodata_e = .;
        . = ALIGN(2);
    } > FLASH_BOOT
    
    .data :  {
        . = ALIGN(2);
        _data_s = .;
        *(.data)
        *(.data*)
        _data_e = .;
        . = ALIGN(2);
    } > SRAM AT > FLASH_BOOT
    
    .bss (NOLOAD):  {
        . = ALIGN(2);
        _bss_s = .;
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _bss_e = .;
    } > SRAM
    
    HEAP_SIZE = (ORIGIN(SRAM) + LENGTH(SRAM)) - _heap_s - STACK_SIZE;
        
    .heap (NOLOAD): {
        . = ALIGN(2);
        _heap_s = .;
        . = . + HEAP_SIZE;
        _heap_e = .;
    } > SRAM
    
    .stack (NOLOAD):  {
        . = ALIGN(2);
        _stack_s = .;
        . = . + STACK_SIZE;
        _stack_e = .;
    } > SRAM
}
```

For the `.bss` section I use symbols in the linker script, which I use in assembly to zero out the `.bss` section. I wrote these functions to get the start and end from the `.bss` section:

```
/* Get .bss start */
FUNCTION(asm_self_get_bss_s)
    ldi r24, lo8(_bss_s)
    ldi r25, hi8(_bss_s)
    ret

/* Get .bss end */
FUNCTION(asm_self_get_bss_e)
    ldi r24, lo8(_bss_e)
    ldi r25, hi8(_bss_e)
    ret
```

How can I get the load address (FLASH) of the `.data` section in the linker script to copy (initialize) the data from the FLASH in the SRAM? The symbols `_data_s` and `_data_e` in my linker script returning the SRAM addresses. But how can I get also the address from the FLASH? Is there a maybe a special function with GNU-ld?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

`LOADADDR()` is the correct function to get the load address from the `.data` section in the linker script.

> LOADADDR(section)
> Return the absolute load address of the named section. This is normally the same as ADDR, but it may be different if the AT keyword
> is used in the section definition (see section Optional Section
> Attributes).

[Quote from GNU linker manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html)

The following works now with my *improved* linker script:

```
    .data :  {
        . = ALIGN(2);
        _data_s_load = LOADADDR(.data);
        _data_s = .;
        *(.data)
        *(.data*)
        _data_e = .;
        . = ALIGN(2);
    } > SRAM AT > FLASH_BOOT
```

And the specific assembly functions:

```
/* Get .data start */
FUNCTION(asm_self_get_data_s)
    ldi r24, lo8(_data_s)
    ldi r25, hi8(_data_s)
    ret

/* Get .data end */
FUNCTION(asm_self_get_data_e)
    ldi r24, lo8(_data_e)
    ldi r25, hi8(_data_e)
    ret

/* Get .data start (load address) */
FUNCTION(asm_self_get_data_s_load)
    ldi r22, lo8(_data_s_load)
    ldi r23, hi8(_data_s_load)
    ldi r24, hh8(_data_s_load)
    eor r25, r25
    ret
```

I can copy (initialize) the data from FLASH to SRAM with the instruction `elpm` now.